# Batch script to get total,free,available size of disks

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic, fsutil

Thanx in advance

I want to create a batch script using which I get all the drives used space, available space, and total space and store it in to the table.

Please help me. i found fsutil command but failed to retrieve result.

Comment: You should not include 'thanks' in posts. See this meta post: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?
Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: use `Powershell -Nop -C "Get-Volume|? DriveType -eq Fixed|sort DriveLetter"`

Comment: Try `wmic LogicalDisk get` or `wmic Volume get`...

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Save this as a batch file, and double-click it, your information should be written to CSV along side it.

```bat
<!-- :
@(Echo Drive,Size[GB],Used[GB],Available[GB]
    @CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf")>"MyDriveInfo.csv"
@Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each oD In o.Drives:If oD.IsReady=True Then
  Wscript.Echo oD.DriveLetter & ":," &_
  Round(oD.TotalSize/1073741824,2) & "," &_
  Round((oD.TotalSize-oD.FreeSpace)/1073741824,2) & "," &_
  Round(oD.AvailableSpace/1073741824,2)
Else:Wscript.Echo oD.DriveLetter & ":,,,":End If:Next
</Script></Job>
```